# VBA Error 438 - trying to copy Excel charts to existing Ppt presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to copy charts from Excel to an existing Powerpoint Template using VBA. This code returns Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method:

```
'Create a new Powerpoint session
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    '
    pptApp.Visible = msoTrue
    'Create a new presentation
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open("....potx")
    Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation
    '
    pptApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
'
    Current_slide = pptPres.Slides.FindBySlideID(258)
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      'Verify if there is a chart object to transfer
      If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objChartObject In ws.ChartObjects
          Set objChart = objChartObject.Chart
          'ppLayoutBlank = 12
          Set pptSld = pptPres.Slides.FindBySlideID(Current_slide)
          pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (pptSld)
          With objChart
           'Copy chart object as picture
            objChart.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap, xlScreen
            'Paste copied chart picture into new slide
            pptSld.Shapes.Paste.Select
            pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
            pptApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
          End With
          Current_slide = Current_slide + 1
        Next objChartObject
      End If
    Next ws
```

Comment: Which line has the error?  You can find that out by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: I see lot of errors here. could you please post the complete code with the declarations on top?

Comment: You can get rid of `Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation` because you already set that variable in the preceding line. You can get rid of this `If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then` because the `For each objChartObject...` loop will take care of that. Otherwise, as others have indicated, please tell us WHERE the error is happening, and post the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at top of module:

Option Explicit

Then try it with these changes (aircode, mostly, but it's a start):

```
Dim Current_slide as Long
Dim pptSlide as PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oShRange as PowerPoint.ShapeRange

' I don't know why exactly you're using FindBySildeID
' Care to explain that?
Current_slide = pptPres.Slides.FindBySlideID(258).SlideIndex

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      'Verify if there is a chart object to transfer

' Don't really need this; if count is 0, the code within the
' For Each loop won't execute:
'      If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objChartObject In ws.ChartObjects
          Set objChart = objChartObject.Chart
          'ppLayoutBlank = 12
'         This needs a LONG not an object, so 
          Set pptSld = pptPres.Slides.FindBySlideID(Current_slide)

' You don't really need to GoTo the slide in order to operate on it          
' Doing so will slow things down; if you want to see it work, though, 
' uncomment:
'         pptApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (pptSld)

          With objChart
           'Copy chart object as picture
            objChart.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap, xlScreen

            'Paste copied chart picture into new slide
'            pptSld.Shapes.Paste.Select
            Set oShRange = pptSld.Shapes.Paste
            With oShRange
              .Align msoAlignCenters, True
              .Align msoAlignMiddles, True
            End With  ' oShRange

          End With  
          Current_slide = Current_slide + 1
        Next objChartObject
 '     End If
    Next ws
```